# I need an example on attaching a field collection to a form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have some field collections that are attached to a node type and I am in the process of writing a custom form, using Drupal's Form API.

How do I go about loading these field collection fields into the form? Should I use `hook_form`, `hook_field`, or something else?

Can someone provide me a simple example of writing a form element that is a field collection with unlimited cardinality?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the following code to load field collection form. I have added extra comments and removed custom logic that hunts for field values from $form_state['values'] variable.

```
function mymodule_custom_form($form, $form_state, $args ){
  $form = array();
  $type = $args['type'];
  $id = $args['id'];
  module_load_include('inc', 'field_collection', 'field_collection.pages');
  if(!empty($entity->field_comments[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) ){
    $field_collection_item = field_collection_item_load($entity->field_comments[$entity->language][0]['value'], TRUE);
    $output = drupal_get_form('field_collection_item_form', $field_collection_item);
  }else{
    $output = field_collection_item_add('field_comments', 'node', $entity->nid);
  }  
  dpm($output);
  // If you want to use field collection form submit handlers as is, just return the below   
  // In case you want to use your own custom submit handlers then do modify the $output array as seems fit.
  $form['field_collection_element'] = $output;
  // You may also attach the $output array to your custom form array. Make sure you handle submit handlers properly

  return $form;
}
```

A sample submit handler
@see in submit handler you can use the example given in [here](http://drupal.org/node/1459952#comment-6462658)

```
function mymodule_custom_form_submit( $form, $form_state ){
  ...
  if(empty($item_id)){
    $field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => $field_name ));
    $field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $node);
  }
  else {
    $items = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($item_id));
    $field_collection_item = $items[$item_id];
  }
  if( is_object($field_collection_item)){
    // for references.
    $field_collection_item->field1[$node->language][0]['target_id'] = $field1_val;
    // normal values
    $field_collection_item->field2[$node->language][0]['value'] = $field2_val;
    $field_collection_item->field3[$node->language][0]['value'] = $field3_val;
    if(empty($item_id)){
      $field_collection_item->save( FALSE );
    }
    else{
      $field_collection_item->save( TRUE );
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to populate a node with content using a form, you could always expose the node form to the user and hook_form_alter to hide elements on a user access basis.

Or if you are looking for a fieldable form, you could use [entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) and then use rules to populate other content.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another concept of grouped fields in Drupal forms called

> [Fieldset](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#fieldset)

This allows to Format a group of form items. Example on the forms api page is for contact module with the code below.

```
function contact_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#user_category'] == 'account') {
    $account = $form['#user'];
    $form['contact'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Contact settings'),
      '#weight' => 5,
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['contact']['contact'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Personal contact form'),
      '#default_value' => !empty($account->data['contact']) ? $account->data['contact'] : FALSE,
      '#description' => t('Allow other users to contact you via a <a href="@url">personal contact form</a> which keeps your e-mail address hidden. Note that some privileged users such as site administrators are still able to contact you even if you choose to disable this feature.', array('@url' => url("user/$account->uid/contact"))),
    );
  }
}
```

Thus if your intention is to just group various kinds of fields togather then this is also a way to do it.